# Stereo vision setup to obtain depth map

Tags: cameras, stereo-vision, kinect

I am currently working on a project that requires me to obtain **depth** information and point cloud map of objects in an indoor environment ( roughly twice the size of a normal room). I would like to know -

1. Would a set of >=2 stereo cameras (manually calibrated wireless sricam SP019 IP cameras) be a good choice to produce a map for the entire room ? I will be using OpenCV 3.3.1 for the calibration and depth mapping.
2. If I wanted to increase the range of my stereo pair, would I have to -

   a) increase the baseline distance and keep them parallel ? There is some 
    discussion [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-to-select-cameras-for-a-stereo-vision-system) about the baseline and it's effect on accuracy.
   However, there is no mention about the alignment of the two cameras.

   b) Align them in a tilted fashion to face each other ? Would this 
   be bad for Image rectification ?

What sort of min-max Range can be achieved using >=2 wireless IP cameras in a stereo-vision setup ?

3. I would like to evaluate accuracy of depth measurements obtained from the IP cameras. I am planning to use Kinect depth images (for short ranges 0.8-5 metres) as a reference.

   What are better commercial solutions for obtaining depth map for **longer** ranges ? I have seen a few discussions on StereoLabs Zed cameras (see [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7549/question-for-those-who-have-experience-using-stereo-cameras-module-e-g-zed-du) and [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7397/selecting-hardware-stereo-camera-for-beginners)) but none that are convincing enough to make me buy it, as it is quite expensive.

I am aware similar questions like [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/stereo-camera-vs-kinect?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=77b9fdaec76a4f199c9d27b80f9bd36a) have been asked but it did not contain any discussion on IP cameras.

I am interested in the **personal experience** of people who may have done something similar.

Thank you very much for reading.